# Register Dependency Property Bind in Codebehind

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, dependency-properties

**The question is how to setup a dependency Property to bind it to any other Dependency Property and release it later.**

There is one Dependency Property in UserControl1

```
#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub RaisePropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

#End Region



#Region "BorderSize"

    Dim _BorderSize As Double = 1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the BorderSize property. This observable property 
    ''' indicates ....
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overridable Property BorderSize() As Double
        Get
            Return _BorderSize
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If _BorderSize <> value Then
                _BorderSize = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("BorderSize")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region
```

One Dependency Property in a public shared Class.

```
Public Class MyPublicClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub RaisePropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

#End Region


#Region "BorderSize"

    Dim _BorderSize As Double = 1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the BorderSize property. This observable property 
    ''' indicates ....
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property BorderSize() As Double
        Get
            Return _BorderSize
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If _BorderSize <> value Then
                _BorderSize = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("BorderSize")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

End Class
```

On MainWindow.xaml.vb (Codebehind) it is needed to unregister the old usercontrol and register the new selected usercontrol to setup the Shared MyPublicClass with the properties of new usercontrol.

**How to unregister and register a dependency property manually in codebehind?**

*****  Solved  *****

```
Dim myDataObject As New MyData(DateTime.Now)
Dim myBinding As New Binding("MyDataProperty")
myBinding.Source = myDataObject
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myText, TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Binding object, then set out on the target using SetBinding.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx